# how to check the value of the largest of the search?

Tags: php, arrays, math

If I have data like this:

```
$data1 = array(40, 'P1');
$data2 = array(70, 'P3');
$data3 = array(35, 'P2');
$data4 = array(55, 'P3');
$data5 = array(25, 'P1');
```

how can find data more than 50?
eg:

70> 50;

55> 50;

help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), so in php 5.3 code will looks like this:

```
$data1 = array(40, 'P1');
$data2 = array(70, 'P3');
$data3 = array(35, 'P2');
$data4 = array(55, 'P3');
$data5 = array(25, 'P1');

$data = array($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5);
$result = array_filter($data, function($_item) {
    return $_item[0] > 50;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
//set your array into 2 dimentional array
$data=array();
array_push($data,$data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5);

//get the data
foreach($data as $datum){
    if ($datum[0]>50) echo $datum[1].'<br />';
}
```